# JQuery Code not working in IE9 or lower versions

Tags: javascript, jquery

EDIT*

In one of the pages in our website there is a pirate with a speech bubble that tells jokes. When the bubble is clicked the joke changes to another one at random in the list. For some reason this will not work in IE9 or lower. Can anyone tell me why?

I have checked the console and this error appears

```
"CE2.w.external.InPrivateFilteringEnabled is not a function"
```

Here is the script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var list = $(".joke-list li").toArray();
    var elemlength = list.length;

    // Encapsulate random value assignment within a function
    var setRandomValue = function(element) {
        var randomnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * elemlength);
        var randomitem = list[randomnum];
        $(element).html($(randomitem).text());
    }

    // Bind click button
    $('.speech').click(function () {
        setRandomValue(this);
    });

    // Set random value for the first time
    setRandomValue($('.speech'));
    $('.speech').css("width: 1000px;");
});
```

Here is a fiddle that I have thrown together to show the fault: http://jsfiddle.net/uRd6N/116/

Comment: what's not working ? use console.log & narrow down source of problem

Comment: `$('.speech').css("width", "1000px");`

Comment: It just doesn't show anything after the first click @mikakun

Comment: Does this only happen in IE9 or have you tried it in Chrome/FF too?

Comment: what error is it throwing up ?

Comment: Works fine in chrome/FF. @FrançoisWahl

Comment: I took the $('.speech').css("width", "1000px"); line out and still has issues @AspiringAqib

Comment: CE2.w.external.InPrivateFilteringEnabled is not a function @MandeepJain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this, simpler & cleaner code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var list = $(".joke-list").find("li").map(function(){return $(this).text();});

 // Bind click 
$(document.body).on('click','.speech', function () {
  var rndnum=Math.floor(Math.random() * list.length);
  console.log(rndnum); 
   $(this).html(list[rndnum]);
});
//first rand joke 
$(".speech").trigger("click");
```

});

after seeing your html i guess your problem is that your speech div is parent of your joke list

Comment: Still no joy in IE @mikakun

Comment: @Milo-J that's not helping yourself man... i wrote tens of such plugin & they always working, maybe a typo somewhere. do you know how to use the console ? or make a fiddle to provide your li & paste this code because it will work !

Comment: @Milo-J ; made it more simpler; check your console & console.log at each step to find out what's wrong

Comment: It says "$(document.body).on is not a function" @mikakun

Comment: @Milo-J 1.4.4 in the fiddle

Comment: do you have a link to the plugin @mikakun

Comment: @Milo-J see edit, your html is pretty weird, i'd start by cleaning it up + in fact why put your jokes in the html ? why not directly in the js ?

Comment: @Milo-J none published, all used for specific dev

Answer (score 0):

I suppose it's the missing semicolon in the function assigment. Try this:

```
// Encapsulate random value assignment within a function
var setRandomValue = function(element) {
   [...]
}; // add semicolon here
```

Comment: I ran it in IE9 and it worked fine I guess. What is not working? Is it not showing up at all or is nothing happening when you click? Please be a little bit more specific!

Comment: Check the new fiddle I posted. When you click on the speech bubble it is supposed to go through jokes, but in IE it stops after the first @acme

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a `;` at your function below.

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
var list = $(".joke-list li").toArray();
var elemlength = list.length;

// Encapsulate random value assignment within a function
var setRandomValue = function(element) {
    var randomnum = Math.floor(Math.random() * elemlength);
    var randomitem = list[randomnum];
    element.html($(randomitem).text());
};// <----';' is missing here ie will create issues here

// Bind click button
$('.speech').click(function () {
    setRandomValue($(this));
});

    // Set random value for the first time
    setRandomValue($('.speech'));
    $('.speech').css("width","1000px"); //<---apply css this way;
});
```

see if this solves your issue.

Comment: This still hasn't solved the issue i am afraid. Any other ideas? @jai